# Replacing slashes with dashes in URL Rewriting

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How do I accomplish URL rewriting for the following with `mod_rewrite` in Apache?

- Pretty Link : `www.mysite.com/pages/category/page/`
- Actual File : `www.mysite.com/html/category-page.html`

I only want to rewrite URLs if they contain the domain and the `pages` directory. In all other cases I want the server to work normally.

I've come up with this but would like to know how to replace slashes with dashes:

```
RewriteEngine On
#Look for the word "pages" followed by a slash, and then the article title
RewriteRule   ^pages/(.+)$   html/$1.html   [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

See if the following rule set works:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^pages/(.+?)/?$ html/$1.html [N]
RewriteRule ^html/([^/]+)/(.*)$ html/$1-$2 [N]
```